# QuickSight or Elasticsearch - Column wise aggregration

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-quicksight

Is this possible to do in QuickSight or Elasticsearch? I have tried calculated fields in QuickSight and runtime scripts in Elasticsearch, not sure how to do it? Also, is what I'm not what I'm expecting is even possible in this tool.

Trying out a simple date difference between columns based on their action, here... "*Time taken for 'creating a post' after a user registered"*

**Data Input:**

[image]

**Data output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html)

**Data**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index121",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "aqJ3HnoBF6_U07qsNY-s",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : "Jen",
          "activity" : "Logged In",
          "activity_Time" : "2020-01-08"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index121",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "a6J3HnoBF6_U07qsXY_8",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : "Jen",
          "activity" : "Created a post",
          "activity_Time" : "2020-05-08"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index121",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bKJ3HnoBF6_U07qsk4-0",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : "Mark",
          "activity" : "Logged In",
          "activity_Time" : "2020-01-03"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index121",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "baJ3HnoBF6_U07qsu48g",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "user" : "Mark",
          "activity" : "Created a post",
          "activity_Time" : "2020-01-08"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Query**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user.keyword",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "distinct_sum_feedback": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "state.docs = []",
            "map_script": """ Map span = [
                                           'timestamp':doc['activity_Time'],
                                           'activity':doc['activity.keyword'].value
                                         ];
                              state.docs.add(span)
                          """,
            "combine_script": "return state.docs;",
            "reduce_script": """
                                  def all_docs = [];
                                  for (s in states) 
                                  {
                                      for (span in s) {
                                      all_docs.add(span);
                                    }
                                  }
                                  all_docs.sort((HashMap o1, HashMap o2)->o1['timestamp'].getValue().toInstant().toEpochMilli().compareTo(o2['timestamp'].getValue().toInstant().toEpochMilli()));
                                  
                                  Hashtable result= new Hashtable();
                                  boolean found = false;
                                  JodaCompatibleZonedDateTime loggedIn;
                                  for (s in all_docs) 
                                  {
                                      if(s.activity =='Logged In')
                                      {
                                        loggedIn=s.timestamp.getValue();
                                        found= true;
                                      }
                                      
                                      if(s.activity =='Created a post' && found==true)
                                      {
                                         found=false;
                                         
                                         def dt=loggedIn.getYear()+ '-' + loggedIn.getMonth() + '-' + loggedIn.getDayOfMonth();
                                         
                                         def diff= s.timestamp.getValue().toInstant().toEpochMilli() - loggedIn.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
                                         
                                         if(result.get(dt) == null)
                                         {
                                             result.put(dt, diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 )
                                         }
                                      }
                                  }
                                      
                                  return result;
                           """
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"user" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Jen",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "distinct_sum_feedback" : {
            "value" : {
              "2020-JANUARY-8" : 121
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Mark",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "distinct_sum_feedback" : {
            "value" : {
              "2020-JANUARY-3" : 5
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

**Explanation**

1. "init_script":

> Executed prior to any collection of documents. Allows the aggregation
> to set up any initial state.

Have declared a Map"

2. "map_script"

> Executed once per document collected
> Loop through all document and add activity and timestamp to map

3. combine_script

> Executed once on each shard after document collection is complete

Return collection of Map for all shards

4. reduce_script

> Executed once on the coordinating node after all shards have returned their results

Once again go through through all Map and create a single collection and sort on timestamp. Then go through sorted Map and insert logged in and next "created post" time (diff of logged in and post created time)

Comment: Thanks @jaspreet. Why this would be bad for performance?

Comment: @sk8terboi87ツ it is a script , it will run through all documents and perform calculation. Elastic search is faster when data is in ready made format ie when you are just filtering things